# how to make the first for statement to appear on new line

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make the output like:

```
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

```
grid = [
              ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'] ,
              ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'] ,
              ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'] ,
              ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'] ,
              ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'] ,
              ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'] ,
              ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'] ,
              ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'] ,
              ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
       ]
x = 0
y = 0

for y in range(0,6):
    for x in range(0,9):
        print(grid[x][y] , end = '')
```

but the output is :
`..OO.OO...OOOOOOO..OOOOOOO...OOOOO.....OOO.......O....`
what should to the code so that it shows the output of first 'for' condition on new line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick to `for` loops, you may have to create a `line` variable to print only once when you collected all of your new line:

```
for y in range(0,6): 
    line = "" 
    for x in range(0,9): 
        line += grid[x][y] 
    print(line)
```

Gives:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

Otherwise, a quick way to solve this is to transpose `grid` (thanks to [np.ndarray.T](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html)).
Then convert into strings.

```
>>> print("\n".join("".join(l) for l in np.array(grid).T)) 

..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

Comment: but is it possible in the code i have mentioned?? btw thanks ... this way is also good

Answer (score 1):

No need for numpy methonds or other imports.

You can transpose your lists using [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and use [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join them before printing:

```
grid = [
              ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'] ,
              ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'] ,
              ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'] ,
              ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'] ,
              ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'] ,
              ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'] ,
              ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'] ,
              ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'] ,
              ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
       ]
x = 0
y = 0

transposed = '\n'.join(''.join(k) for k in zip(*grid))
print(transposed)
```

Output:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

Comment: `zip(*grid)` as a transpose :mindblown: that's elegant